# Module exports and method call

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to developp a module with nodejs. My code is something like this :

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.method1 = function () {
   // Some stuff
}

module.exports.method2 = function ()
{
   // Some stuff
 }
```

I would like to do something like :

```
module.exports.method2 = function (url, dir, name)
{
   this.method1();
 }
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it a little bit swankier you could do something like:

```
module.exports = {
    function1: function(){
        //some stuff
    },

    function2: function(){
        this.function1();
    }
};
```

If you want private scope:

```
module.exports = function(){
    var myPrivateVar = 'foo';

    var publicObject = {
        function1: function(){
            //some stuff
            console.log(myPrivateVar);
        },

        function2: function(){
            this.function1();
        }
    };

    return publicObject;
}
```

The difference is though that you need to invoke it where the former is just an object reference.  The second example is more like a constructor function... require + invoke... var myMod = myModule();  myMod.function2() will output 'foo'

IMHO this is a more object-oriented way of doing it rather than exporting each individual function.  This allows for better separation and cleaner code.

Comment: Hi. In this case, it's different to put a var befor or after the "module.exports = " ?

Comment: If you want private variables that have scope to all members of the object, you could make the exports = function(){ .. } but then you have to create an object that has members that is returned by the function.  I'll add to my example

Answer (score 2):

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.method1 = function () {
   // Some stuff
}

exports.method2 = function ()
{
   exports.method1();
 }
```